# Enable Android bluetooth from documentation

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to get my Activity to enable Bluetooth with the Android 2.0.1 SDK, I am using some code straight from the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Which is:

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

I get an error at the REQUEST_ENABLE_BT part where Eclipse says it cannot be resolved. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `REQUEST_ENABLE_BT` part is a request code that you should handle in your `onActivityResult` method.  In that method you'll be notified whether or not enabling Bluetooth was successful.

In that code snippet they didn't show the definition of it, but it's just a constant integer so you can set it to any value you like.

See the [documentation for startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) for more info about getting results back from activity launches.