# Bluetooth discoverability request and screen orientation

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Asking user the permission to turn device discoverable with the following snippet

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);

startActivityForResult(intent, BT_REQUEST);
```

causes the following system dialog to show up in portrait mode while my calling activity is in landscape, which is not a good user experience.

[image]

Many landscape only bluetooth apps I tried from the Play Store seem to suffer the same problem.

Is there any way to force the dialog to appear in landscape mode?

I tried to override system activity orientation from manifest, without success

```
<activity android:name="com.android.settings.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity"
                        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Comment: I think, you start another app by using intent, which makes it impossible to use landscape. So maybe you can make a confirmation alert dialog inside your app and send Bluetooth adapter positive or negative selection automatically from your dialog.

Comment: For security reasons, I think it is not possible..

Comment: Check out ifeegoo's answer to this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546083/how-to-turn-on-bluetooth-on-button-click . But as you said, and ifeegoo states, security might block turning on bluetooth if you use enable() method.